# Unable to import PyGI module 'Gtk' - No module named 'gi'

Tags: python, pip, refactoring

I'm trying to run `textest &` on Mac to follow along [GildedRose-Refactoring-Kata](https://github.com/emilybache/GildedRose-Refactoring-Kata/tree/main/texttests) but I keep running into this error message

```
> texttest &
[1] 58365
peter.walker in ~/dev-projects/gildedrose-ruby-kata on branch main > Could not start TextTest 4.1.3 GUI due to PyGI/PyGObject GUI library problems :
Unable to import PyGI module 'Gtk' - No module named 'gi'

[1]  + exit 1     texttest
```

I have tried installing python3-gi but I'm confronted with

```
> pip3 install python3-gi
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-gi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3-gi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GUI started running after `brew install pygobject3 gtk+3`